# Destination address of 82C37A DMA Controller

Tags: verilog, dma

How do I select the destination address for the [82C37A DMA controller](http://www.embeddedsys.com/subpages/resources/images/documents/82C37_datasheet.pdf)? I have gone through all the material on the web and they say that the Base Address and Current Address register contains the source address. So, how do I select the destination address? Should the DMAC just send the data onto the data bus and not worry about the destination? Or am I misreading something?

Comment: The datasheet says "The 82C37A is designed to be used with an external address latch," does that mean anything to you?

Comment: basically an external device is the one that passes on the data to another device, and you manipulate the external device to mux however you want

Answer (score 1):

To do a memory to memory dma transfer, the 82c37 uses 2 channels. Ch0 reads from the source and Ch1 writes to the destination. So to set the destination address you need to write to the address registers for Ch1. From pg 4 of the datasheet under the memory-to-memory section. If my memory serves me correctly this functionality was somehow broken in the original PC/XT/AT design ...